# Crashlytics asks for dSYMs with UUIDs that don't match my app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, crashlytics, google-fabric

I uploaded a new version `1.1` of my app to `iTunesConnect` and caused a couple of test crashes with `Crashlytics`.  I added, via the [Upload Symbols Script](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols), the `dSYMs` that I downloaded from `iTunesConnect` since I had `Enable Bitcode` set to `YES`.

The problem is that the `6 dSYM` files that I uploaded do not match the `UUID`'s that Fabric requests.  It asks for 2 separate `UUIDs` and neither match.

[image]

My `dSYMs` downloaded from `iTunesConnect`:

[image]

Note that version `1.0` was NOT uploaded with `Enable Bitcode` set to `YES` and also, for that version, the UUIDs don't match.

Am I missing something here?  Should I contact support or can anybody help me solve this?

**EDIT:**

Here are the 'local' dSYMs, from `Xcode`:

[image]

Here are the 'remote' dSYMs, from `iTunesConnect`:

[image]

As I understand, Apple change the `dSYMs` so I've no idea where the `UUIDs` in the screenshot come from!!!

And, pressing 'Download dSYMS...' in Xcode downloads the SAME dSYMs that I downloaded from `iTunesConnect`, as expected.  It remains a mystery where `Crashlytics` gets those `UUIDs` from.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I think I already replied back to an email on this, but using upload-symbols won't help as the dSYMs mismatch. Can you try downloading them via Xcode and see if you get different dSYMs then ITunesConnect?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi Mike, I edited my question to include the dSYM details.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dave, if you open them up - right-click -> Get Info - do any of those values match the missing dSYM. For what it's worth, the way we show the missing dSYMs is when a crash comes in, we look for the UUID of the dSYM needed to symbolicate it and report those. They could also be coming from Static frameworks.

Comment: @MikeBonnell No.  Right clicking the dSYMs and selecting 'Get Info' just shows the name and extension already visible in the file name.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Is there a way to 'reinstall' Crashlytics on the project so it works?  I really would like it to report any crashes!

Comment: Yep, you definitely can. Check out https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install The missing dSYM issue may not be solved by that, so I'd also recommend looking at https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#static-or-dynamic-frameworks

Comment: @Mike Bonnell ok! Thanks for the help. I'll report back here if I get it solved.

Comment: @DaveChambers Did you resolve this?

Comment: @GregHilston No Greg, sadly I didn't.  Right now I have bigger fish to fry but I promise to update this post if I have any news.

Comment: Understood. I will be as well, I'll tag you of I figure something out.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue : Crashlytics asks for UUIDs that don't exist on iTunesConnect. Was this solved somehow?

Comment: @Konstantinos Gaitanis No solution I'm afraid. I'll let you know if there's any update.

Comment: Still no news on this?

Comment: @Wiingaard I don't use Crashlytics any more. It doesn't work

Comment: Do do use crash tracking service then?

Comment: @Wiingaard Nope. I just make sure my code doesn't crash!

Comment: Hah, that's great advice :) How about @MikeBonnell, do you have any updated on how to find these seemingly disappeared dSYMs?

Comment: Hey @Wiingaard this post has veered in many different directions. We look for dSYMs based on the UUID needed to symbolicate the crash report. The most common case is that you have Bitcode enabled and Apple has provided the wrong dSYMs via iTunesConnect. Downloading them Xcode instead has proven effective for some developers. The other issue is that you're not creating dSYMs for some frameworks and libraries you're bundling with your app. In short, this is immensely complicated and depends on each project's specific build settings.

Comment: anyone solved the issue ?